# can anyone explain output for the below javascript question?

Tags: javascript

```js
const doSomething = (foo) => {
  foo.push('rsa')
  foo = ["World"]
  return foo;
}

let blah = ["Hello"];
console.log(blah);
doSomething(blah);
console.log(blah);
```

**Please Explain me the output**

> output will be like below
> I am really confused with javascript so please can anyone explain this.

output will be like below
I am really confused with javascript so please can anyone explain this.

output will be like below
I am really confused with javascript so please can anyone explain this.

```
[
  "Hello"
]
[
  "Hello",
  "rsa"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that arrays are passed as references (pointers if you like)
In your function you made `foo` point to another array but the original array is still in memory

```js
const doSomething = (foo) => {
  foo.push('rsa')
  foo = ["World"] // foo is a local variable that references an array, you changed it locally. The original array still exists.
  return foo;
}

let blah = ["Hello"];
console.log(blah); // this is obvious
doSomething(blah); // you are passing the array reference to doSomething(). that function pushes 'rsa'
console.log(blah); //you print the array with the pushed 'rsa' item
```